# Deploying an Access Database as a Product

Tags: ms-access, deployment, installation, package

I have a simple question. I am new to the development world, and have created some fairly decent access databases. These databases are geared towards the small business owner. Currently I have a few small businesses whom are interested in the databases that I have created as a potential product to purchase. How and what is the best way to go about packaging an access database so that the user does not have to have a full copy of access, and also so that the product can be updated in the future. For instance version 1.1 might be the launch version, but 1.2 may contain the date and time on the splash screen of the database?

If more information is needed please let me know I will be glad to upload more information.

The Access database that I am using is Access 2013.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a simple setup that has worked for me:

- Convert to .accde.
- Give users Access Runtime.
- Split Database.
- Place updated frontend into Dropbox account shared with client.
- Instruct client how to find backend when prompted using the following code on your startup screen load event.

`Private Sub Form_Load()
        On Error GoTo frm_error
        Dim RS As Recordset
        Dim cn As Database
        Set cn = CurrentDb
        Set RS = cn.OpenRecordset("tblX") 'Insert name of any table in backend
        RS.Close
        Exit Sub
    frm_error:
        If MsgBox("Database cannot be found.  Advanced Users press OK to link the tables.  Otherwise, notify an admin and press cancel to close the xProgram.", vbOKCancel) = vbOK     Then
            RunCommand acCmdLinkedTableManager
        Else
            DoCmd.Quit
        End If
    End Sub`

I will note that I have since stopped using access as a backend and switched to SQL Server hosted by Amazon RDS.  This does wonders for security, backup, front-end upgrades, and off-site maintenance (though I will stress that you will never get a fully secure system using access as a frontend).

Answer (score 3):

That's a pretty broad question.  Entire chapters of books have been written on that topic.  I'll simply give you the short, short explanation:

---

*How and what is the best way to go about packaging an access database so that the user does not have to have a full copy of access?*

The simplest thing to do here is to compile your database file to an .mde or .accde.  It's not bullet-proof but will deter the casual user from reverse-engineering your product.

Starting with Access 2007, the Access Runtime is available free of charge.  Using the runtime your users won't have access to the database window (the thing that lists all your tables, queries, forms, reports, etc) so you'll need to provide alternate navigation for that.

---

*And also so that the product can be updated in the future*

I've read good things about Tony Toews's [Auto FE Updater](http://autofeupdater.com/).  I've not used it personally (I use a combination of Inno Setup and other custom scripts I've written), but I've heard it works well for what you are talking about.

---

One last point.  **You absolutely must split your database** into a front-end and back-end before distributing it.

Comment: Yes, front-end / back-end separation is crucial. It allows you to deploy a new version of your app, while keeping your customers data in the back-end untouched. You will have to implement a mechanism that allows the app to link the back-end tables automatically at startup, since the file path of the back-end will most probably not be the same as on your development PC.

Comment: Thank you, So if I am planning on packaging the database onto a thumb drive for deployment and installation purposes Is this a good approach to ensure that the instalation path is always the same ?